# Save a two dimensional array in R in netcdf

Tags: arrays, r, file, netcdf

I want to save a "slice" map from a dataset to a new netcdf file.  The code in question is as follows:

```
library(ncdf)
ncfname <- “cru10min30_tmp.nc”
crutmp <- open.ncdf(ncfname)

tmp.array <- get.var.ncdf(crutmp,"tmp")
close.ncdf(crutmp)
month <- 1
tmp.slice <- tmp.array[,,month]
```

The data set is available at http://geography.uoregon.edu/GeogR/data/raster/cru10min30_tmp.nc and this code snippet has been taken from a example give on http://geography.uoregon.edu/GeogR/topics/raster01.htm. How do I save "tmp.slice" two dimensional array as a new netcdf file?

Thanks and let me know if more info is needed to help you analyse the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new NetCDF file first, then add the slice to that newly created file.

Get the dimension values from the source file:

```
lat <- get.var.ncdf(crutmp,"lat")
lon <- get.var.ncdf(crutmp,"lon")
```

Use these arrays to define your dimensions:

```
Lat <- dim.def.ncdf(name = "lat", units = "m", vals = lat)
Lon <- dim.def.ncdf(name = "lon", units = "m", vals = lon)
```

Define a variable along these dimensions:

```
mv <- -9999 # missing value
z <- var.def.ncdf(name = "z", units = "m", dim = list(Lat, Lon), prec="double", missval = mv)
```

Now create a new NetCDF file that contains variable z:

```
newnc <- create.ncdf(filename = "tmp_slice.nc", vars = list(z))
```

Put your time slice values (tmp.slice) in variable z:

```
put.var.ncdf(nc = newnc, varid = "z", vals = tmp.slice, start = c(1,1), count = c(-1,-1))
```

Close newly created NetCDF file to write it to disk:

```
close.ncdf(newnc)
```