# R: how to save multidimensional array to disk with arrow/parquet?

Tags: r, arrays, save, apache-arrow

in R, I would like to save a multidimensional array (say 10 dimensions or more, each dimension with possibly different lengths) to disk in a cross-platform format. For this reason I'm excluding `.rds` files and `saveRDS()`.

If possible I'd like to use the arrow or parquet format, from the [`arrow` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=arrow), but I can't find the right way to save an array. Using `arrow::write_feather()` or`_parquet` gives the error "No method for `as_arrow_table()` for object of class array".

I have found several questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18843447/6090141), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26456980/6090141), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26165980/6090141) that touch on the general problem of saving arrays to disk, but no question or answer seems to use the arrow format. Maybe it isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>**Note:** *This discussion is mostly about the parquet format, which is different in several ways from the feather format. I believe the takeaways are the same, but I don't have as much experience with feather to know for a fact that they are identical.*</sub>

---

From https://parquet.apache.org:

> *Apache Parquet is an open source, column-oriented data file format.*

Column-oriented ("columnar" in other docs) really is just a frame.

A matrix can be stored after converting to a frame first:

```r
matrix(1:20, nrow = 4) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  arrow::write_parquet("mtx.pq")
arrow::read_parquet("mtx.pq")
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     5     9    13    17
# 2     2     6    10    14    18
# 3     3     7    11    15    19
# 4     4     8    12    16    20
```

To get more dimensions in there, you'll need to reshape it for storage. This will benefit from some of the parquet efficiencies, but you don't get the "power" of the parquet filtering in the same way; notably, finding specific slices/planes/subarrays of the original data will take a bit more work and translation.

```r
ary <- array(1:24, dim=2:4)
arylong <- as.data.frame.table(ary)
arylong[,-ncol(arylong)] <- lapply(arylong[,-ncol(arylong),drop=FALSE], function(z) match(z, unique(z)))
arylong
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Freq
# 1     1    1    1    1
# 2     2    1    1    2
# 3     1    2    1    3
# 4     2    2    1    4
# 5     1    3    1    5
# 6     2    3    1    6
# 7     1    1    2    7
# 8     2    1    2    8
# 9     1    2    2    9
# 10    2    2    2   10
# 11    1    3    2   11
# 12    2    3    2   12
# 13    1    1    3   13
# 14    2    1    3   14
# 15    1    2    3   15
# 16    2    2    3   16
# 17    1    3    3   17
# 18    2    3    3   18
# 19    1    1    4   19
# 20    2    1    4   20
# 21    1    2    4   21
# 22    2    2    4   22
# 23    1    3    4   23
# 24    2    3    4   24
arrow::write_parquet(arylong, "ary.pq")
arrow::read_parquet("ary.pq")
# # A tibble: 24 × 4
#     Var1  Var2  Var3  Freq
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1     1     1     1
#  2     2     1     1     2
#  3     1     2     1     3
#  4     2     2     1     4
#  5     1     3     1     5
#  6     2     3     1     6
#  7     1     1     2     7
#  8     2     1     2     8
#  9     1     2     2     9
# 10     2     2     2    10
# # ℹ 14 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I included the `lapply(..)` step since the default action of `as.data.frame.table` is to use `Var#` as a *factored* index, i.e., `Var1` is `c(A, B, A, B, ...)`. It's certainly fine to retain those, but I thought for the closest translation from numeric-indexing of arrays, it would be best to stick with numbers.

The basic translation from array-indexing to this could be something like:

```r
ary[1:2,2:3,3:4]
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   15   17
# [2,]   16   18
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   21   23
# [2,]   22   24

library(dplyr)
pqlong <- arrow::open_dataset("ary.pq") |>
  filter(Var1 %in% 1:2, Var2 %in% 2:3, Var3 %in% 3:4) |>
  arrange() |>
  collect()
newary <- array(dim = sapply(pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE], function(z) length(unique(z))))
pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE] <- lapply(pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE], function(z) match(z, unique(z)))
newary[as.matrix(pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE])] <- pqlong[[ncol(pqlong)]]
newary
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   15   17
# [2,]   16   18
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   21   23
# [2,]   22   24
all.equal(newary, ary[1:2,2:3,3:4], check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Notes:

- I'm using `open_dataset` to indicate that this mechanism works well with larger-array datasets where you only need to extract a small portion of it and would prefer to not load all of it into RAM. Loading a large frame and then reshaping imposes a memory-penalty of effectively double the size of the array/table. As such, `dplyr` plays well with `arrow` for lazy filtering/loading before imparting the memory consequence. (However, since `dplyr` also works only on frames, there is no way I know of to do the reshaping logically/lazily.)
- We use `length(unique(z))` because we need to know a priori the target dimensions of `newary`.
- The `match(z, unique(z))` step is required because the matrix indexing will return (e.g.) values 2 and 3 for `Var2`, but the `newary` column indexing should be on 1 and 2, so we match the return values with the unique values in order to fit within `newary`.

Bonus: this works with sparse data as well (even if the target array is not truly a sparse-efficient matrix):

```r
pqlong <- arrow::open_dataset("ary.pq") |>
  filter(Var1 %in% 1:2, Var2 %in% 2:3, Var3 %in% 3:4,
         !Freq %in% c(18, 22)) |>                       # NEW
  arrange() |> collect()

newary <- array(dim = sapply(pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE], function(z) length(unique(z))))
pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE] <- lapply(pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE], function(z) match(z, unique(z)))
newary[as.matrix(pqlong[,-ncol(pqlong),drop=FALSE])] <- pqlong[[ncol(pqlong)]]
newary
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   15   17
# [2,]   16   NA
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   21   23
# [2,]   NA   24
```

Comment: Simply outstanding, thank you for all the work, code, and clear explanation! Maybe I should try some other format then, although this seems to have many advantages even with the workarounds around parquet's column-format (which I didn't know about).

Would you recommend any other format for multidimensional arrays? The answer to the question about "best way to save 3D array" is a bit outdated.

Comment: I'm mildly curious but have no experience in efficient storage (both for speed and compression) of numeric objects with dim > 2. It definitely has utility, I just don't have it in my current workflow to need, sorry.